# Sane way to edit with Excel formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, text-editors, user-interface

Is there any sane way to work with large and complicated Excel formulas?
For a simple `=IF(A1>B2);C3;C4` or something similar, just having it chained behind each other is OK, but if we are getting into lengthy statements¹, this gets unsightly, and more importantly, hard to follow real quick.

E.g. `=IF(A3=OFFSET(A3;1;1);IF((E3>50);D3;IF((E4>50);D4;""));J8)` is really annoying to decipher, or worse, to fix.

**How can I make this more readable?**

Splitting it up and indentation helps, and with `alt + enter` I can add new lines, which can even begin with spaces, so the above becomes

```
=IF(A3=OFFSET(A3;1;1);
    IF((E3>50);
        D3;
        IF((E4>50);
            D4;
            ""));
    J8)
```

which is much better. However, it's still lacking. I have to add all spaces by hand (and without `tab=4 spaces`²), so some autoindent like in about every editor would be helpful. But OK, I can work 80's style if I must, but why on earth is the font not monospaced? Who thought that was a sane idea? And what about comments? And code highlighting? Somehow I can't believe that MS flagship product is stuck in the past³.

**So how do I get (some) of the above helpers, if that's possible at all?**

*¹ Yes, I know, Excel might be the wrong tool for that, but I'm probably not the only person that is wrangling with some historic Excel sheets that have long grown to sizes that even some dedicated database software can't handle anymore*

*² I'm used to python, so just see this as an example, and I'm well aware of the tabs vs. spaces discussion*

*³ OK, I lied, I can totally believe that. Maybe Office 1080 will have an instance of Chrome running in the formal box for this purpose…*

Comment: I think you answered it yourself, Excel is a spreadsheet application, not a programming tool. I copy long formulas to notepad++ to split them when I really need to.

Comment: True, but it does contain a full programming environment, so having some additional tools for that seem logical. And some already exist. I.e. I can get cells color coded (instead of keywords) and it can tell me which part of a formula does what, when I click on it, so the basics are already there. It just seems very inconsequential.

Comment: I think you might be happier writing and applying these formulas in VBA. It has a more 'coding' interface and allows for commenting, tab spacing, and monospaced fonts.(Not sure about code highlighting).